# json technology attached with java script? what is the use of stringifier in it?

Tags: json

How do we use arrays  and object notation in it ? Well how do we post , is JSon a platform dependent or independent language?

Answer (score 3):

JSON is not a language. It is a data interchange format only.

From the [official site](http://json.org/)

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a
>   lightweight data-interchange format.
>   It is easy for humans to read and
>   write. It is easy for machines to
>   parse and generate. It is based on a
>   subset of the JavaScript Programming
>   Language, Standard ECMA-262 3rd
>   Edition - December 1999. JSON is a
>   text format that is completely
>   language independent but uses
>   conventions that are familiar to
>   programmers of the C-family of
>   languages, including C, C++, C#, Java,
>   JavaScript, Perl, Python, and many
>   others. These properties make JSON an
>   ideal data-interchange language.

A ***JSON stringifier*** converts JavaScript data structures into JSON text.

[Read more on stringifier.](http://json.org/js.html)

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not platform dependent.

It is also not language dependent or not. Rather we see if a language supports the conversion from a JSON string to the language's object/array equivalent.

It is just a object notation to represent objects and its properties, arrays and its elements.